# Python bisect and Pandas dataframe: KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bisect

I am using `bisect` for finding the first index that is greater than my value:

```
bisect.bisect_left(X['x'].iloc[116:231], x=0.15)
```

X is in ascending order and the first value `X['x'].iloc[116]` is 0.275. The bisect function above gives me `KeyError: 57`. I have understand that it cannot find the corresponding key but cannot understand why it tries to find the key '57'. My expectation is that the first greater value than 0.15 is 0.275 and it should give me the index 116.

I have used `bisect` because my list is already sorted, but if there is more efficient way to find the first index greater than a specific value I would be pleasure if you let me know.

---

#### Edit:

I have tried with other indexes and `x` values and results are getting strange. The smallest number is 0.125:

```
bisect.bisect_left(X[0:10]['x'], x=0.125)  # works and gives index 0
bisect.bisect_left(X[1:10]['x'], x=0.125)  # KeyError: 0
bisect.bisect_left(X[2:10]['x'], x=0.125)  # KeyError: 1
bisect.bisect_left(X[3:10]['x'], x=0.125)  # KeyError: 1
bisect.bisect_left(X[4:10]['x'], x=0.125)  # KeyError: 3
bisect.bisect_left(X[5:10]['x'], x=0.125)  # KeyError: 2
bisect.bisect_left(X[6:10]['x'], x=0.125)  # KeyError: 2
bisect.bisect_left(X[7:10]['x'], x=0.125)  # KeyError: 1
```

I have tried to debug but could not manage to track the code giving this error.

Comment: How large is your frame? I would suspect the key error comes from your iloc?

Comment: It's length is 231. I have tried with other values and getting more strange results, please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

The `bisect` library is designed to be used with `arrays` not with `pandas.Series`.

The problem in this case arises from the fact that `bisect_left(a, x, lo=0, hi=len(a))` may try to access all elements between `a[lo]` and `a[hi]`. As a `pandas.Series` overwrites the use of the `[]` bracket operator when the `bisect_left` function internally calls `a[0]` it will not call the first element of the passed array but try to acces the element of the series with index `0` which is not present in `X['x'].iloc[116:231]`.

In order to solve your problem you thus have to either cast the `pandas.Series` into for example a `list` and add the index displacement

```
bisect.bisect_left(list(X['x'].iloc[116:231]), x=0.15)+116
```

or specify the limits for `lo` and `hi` explicitly.

```
bisect.bisect_left(X['x'].iloc[116:231], x=0.15, lo=116, hi=231)
```